# Controller and view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit

I have a Controller Products:

```
def update
@product = Product.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
     if @product.brand == nil 
        format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'compositions', :action => 'edit', :id =>  @product } 
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

The controller products call Controller Compositions, action edit and params :id => @product:

```
def edit
   @composition = Composition.where("productFather_id=?" , @product)
end

def update
   @composition = Composition.where("productFather_id=?" , @product)

respond_to do |format|
  if @composition.update_attributes(params[:composition])
    format.html { redirect_to "/compositions/new", notice: 'Composition was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @composition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

I search edit compositions of product in views

PLEASE IDEAS THANKS

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: error: undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Comment: app/views/compositions/_formEdit.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_compositions__form_dit_html_erb__362908564_35236620'
app/views/compositions/_formEdit.html.erb:16:in `each'
app/views/compositions/_formEdit.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_compositions__form_dit_html_erb__362908564_35236620'
app/views/compositions/edit.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_compositions_edit_html_erb__93283969_45444636'

Comment: Paste `app/views/compositions/_formEdit.html.erb`

Comment: <% Product.all.each do |product| %>
 <tr>
 <td><div>
 <%= form_for(@composition) do |f|   %>        <div style="display:none;">          Father: <%= f.text_field :productFather_id, :value => @lastProduct.id  %>
</div>          <div style="display:none;">
Son : <%= f.text_field :productSon_id, :value => product.id%>
</div>        <fieldset>       <legend>Quantity</legen><div class="field">           <%= f.number_field :quantity %>           </div>
       </fieldset>
          <div class="actions" style="text-align: center;">           <%= f.submit "Add" %>         </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

Comment: sorry I can not seem to display properly

Comment: Ok, what exactly do you want to do in this action?
BTW, Rails convention in naming partials/instance variables is to use underscore, like `_form_edit.html.erb`.
Error occurs, because `@composition` is really not one record, but set of records in your edit action.

Comment: product is a compound of one or more products.
for example I have a father product consists of two product son
I edit the father product through the product controller and I want to edit the son products through the controller composition.
through composition controller edit action I display a view of the products and their son quantity then I edit